# laravel 5 won't delete files from storage section

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

when I try to delete specific file trough my controller I get an error

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
>   NotFoundHttpException

This is my controller:

```
public function destroyFile($file_name)
{
    $file = storage_path('documents').'/'.$file_name;
    Storage::delete($file);
    return redirect('/documents');
}
```

My route:

```
  Route::delete('documents/{file}','FilesController@destroyFile');
```

And my view:

```
    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' =>     ['FilesController@destroyFile', $file->name] ]) !!}
                            {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') !!}
                            {!! Form::token() !!}
                            {!! Form::submit(trans('buttons.del-cat'),['class'=>'btn btn-danger user-delete push-right']) !!}
                            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Which request fails...the DELETE to /documents/{file} or the redirect GET to /documents?

Comment: redirect was failing but it still doesn't delete the file in storage

Comment: what does $file evaluate to in the call to `Storage::delete($file)`? Does that file actually exist at the path specified?

Comment: exist($file) says fals but there is a file like that in that path

Comment: it sounds like there's not a file there...double check config and path and extension and everything.

Comment: checked... all is ok but if i do this if(file_exists($file)){
            dd('File is exists.');
        }else{
            dd('File is not exists.');
        } it says that file exists

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, everything was set right but it still didn't work.

Instead of `Storage::delete()` I used `File::delete()`, that fixed it.

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function images(Request $request,$id){
    $user_id=$request->session()->get('user_id');
    $data=DB::table('company_images')->where('id',$id)->first();
    //deleteing the image from database and server
    DB::table('company_images')->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
    //delete the image form the server
    $path=public_path("/assets/img/company/$data->image");
    unlink($path);
    return redirect("/company/$user_id/add_details")->with('delete','delete');

}
```

this is function i used to delete company images using unlink($path) this works well with me also the big note:you should write carefully the path to file you delete.

Answer (score 0):

You must set `public` in `filesystem.php` :

`'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public')`

instead of :

`'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local')`

change `local` to `public`.